# Keras model doesn't predict well

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network, lstm, kaggle

I am currently participating in the Kaggle competition for forecasting COVID-19 cases (week 3).  The goal is to predict COVID-19 cases from a dataset with daily cases for every country.
https://www.kaggle.com/c/covid19-global-forecasting-week-3

My input data for the model look like this:

> t-10, t-9, t-8, ..., t ====> predict t+1
>   t-9, t-8, t-7, ..., t+1 =====> predict t+2
>   ......
>   Where t is a time step
>   
>   After I fit the model, I am trying to predict next 33 time-steps

I'm trying to use Convolutional NNs and LSTMs,
My model looks like this:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(filters=250, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', input_shape=(10,1), padding='same', kernel_initializer='truncated_normal'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(64, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='truncated_normal'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(16, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='truncated_normal'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
```

I'm fitting 5 different models and then averaging their results.
I've tried a lot of different models (by changing the layers or how many nodes there are) but this one seems the best so far.
I'm not sure why but it either doesn't fit well or it overfits. Either case, it still makes awful predictions like 79 cases in one run and 10^4 cases in another.

Here are some plots of my model (the second one is what I am trying to achieve):
[image: bad prediction]
[image: good prediction]

Can you please give me some advice regarding this problem? Should I use a different model, do something on my data, change the number of epochs, etc ...


Thank you in advance!

Comment: 1. use batch normalization after LSTM layer. 2. try with different batch size, epochs and a scheduler.